# OpenFOAM Copiling Error

Tags: 18.04

It's been a week since I start to try install OpenFOAM. 
I'm trying to install OpenFOAM v1806 on my labtop.
Unfortunately I faced some error while I tried to build OpenFOAM with the normal 64-bit integer support by typing "`source $HOME/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/etc/bashrc WM_LABEL_SIZE=64`"

Can you give me any advices or clues to solve this problem?

Thank you in advances.

The error messages are as follows:

```
-bash: eval: line 38: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 38: `PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program:Files:(x86)/Intel/iCLS:Client:Files/Intel/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:(x86)/Intel/Intel(R):Management:Engine:Components/DAL:Files/Intel/Intel(R):Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin'
-bash: eval: line 62: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 62: `PATH=/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/jwhan-v1806/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/bin:/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/site/v1806/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/bin:/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/bin:/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/bin:/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/wmake:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program:Files:(x86)/Intel/iCLS:Client:Files/Intel/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:(x86)/Intel/Intel(R):Management:Engine:Components/DAL:Files/Intel/Intel(R):Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin:'
No completion added for /home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/bin
... incorrect platform, or not yet compiled?
-bash: eval: line 38: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: eval: line 38: `PATH=/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/ThirdParty-v1806/platforms/linux64Gcc/gperftools-2.5/bin:/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/jwhan-v1806/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/bin:/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/site/v1806/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/bin:/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/platforms/linux64GccDPInt64Opt/bin:/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/bin:/home/jwhan/OpenFOAM/OpenFOAM-v1806/wmake:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/mnt/c/Program:Files:(x86)/Intel/iCLS:Client:Files/Intel/iCLS:/mnt/c/Windows/System32:/mnt/c/Windows:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/wbem:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0:/mnt/c/Windows/System32/OpenSSH:(x86)/Intel/Intel(R):Management:Engine:Components/DAL:Files/Intel/Intel(R):Components/IPT:/mnt/c/Users/Administrator/AppData/Local/Microsoft/WindowsApps:/snap/bin'
```

Answer (score 1):

It's all those directories from your `/mnt/c` drive/mount that contain weird characters like parentheses and spaces, confusing the OpenFOAM build script. You have a few options:

1. Umount `/mnt/c` while you build OpenFOAM, once it's built, you can remount.
2. `sudo apt-get install openfoam`; version 4.1 is available on ubuntu 18.04's repositories and you don't need to compile it.

Comment: You're welcome! If it helped, don't forget to "accept" it so it gets marked as the correct answer.